# How to assign a feed to an existing folder in The Old Reader

Tags: the-old-reader

How can I assign a new feed to an existing folder in The Old Reader? If the folder appears on the left (thus has unread items) then I can drag and drop the new feed into the existing folder. However, I cannot figure out how to do it if the folder does not appear there.

I managed to enable showing of folders that have no unread items in the list, but this is not convenient because then the list is long... Any simpler solution?

Answer (score 2):

To the left of the folder names, there is a fold-up arrow.   Click this to hide the list of  subscriptions in each folder.   This makes the list a lot shorter and more manageable.